# windows python cannot run pip from any location except root directory

Tags: python, cmd

I dont know how to word this question but here is the essence of what is going on. I am attempting to run ipython in accordance with the instructions below but I will explain it by way of pip because i am more familiar with it.

In command line If i want to install something with pip i must first navigate to the folder it is located in and then run it e.g.

```
cd "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Scripts
pip install "ipython[notebook]"
```

This works fine, if I am in any other location it will not work. this is fine but I am now trying to run  something like the below in a separate folder and I cannot do it. i dont want to clutter that scripts folder with all of that jazz so i would really like to run ipython outside of the root folder.

```
git clone https://github.com/donnemartin/interactive-coding-challenges.git
cd interactive-coding-challenges
ipython notebook
```

I hope thats clear, it is to me but that isnt saying much.

also that scripts folder is already in env. variables.

to further muddy the water it will work if i include the whole path like below but i would love to just type ipython instead of all of this jazz.

```
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Scripts\ipython.exe notebook
```

Comment: Just to confirm, `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Scripts` and the path to ipython are in the `PATH` environment variable?  Type `PATH` in whatever shell you're using and confirm.

Comment: yes sir and ipython is within this folder along with pip and by that i mean i see a whole mess of ipython.exe and jupyter.exe files modified today when i installed

Comment: "if I am in any other location it will not work" -- do you get an error message and if so, what does it say?

Comment: I get the good old steady ipython is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: I not familiar with ipython, but you can try `python -m pip x` with this you ejecute python with indicated module (`-m`), and x is the commands line argument to say module

Answer (score 0):

You mention, your path is set, but perhaps it was only applied it temporarily? Make sure you use `setx` to make a permanent change:

```
setx path "%path%;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Scripts\"
```

Now *exit the terminal* and start it again - you should be able to run `ipython` from any location

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am getting the old reliable sex is not recognized as an internal or external command. I see setx.exe in C:\Windows, which i added manually via the system properties and i am still geting this error.

Comment: Sounds like something is seriously wrong with your path. Try to reset it using `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ ` using the UI.

Comment: I am a little gun shy to reset all or my variables as there is a bunch of other things in there for this and that done by people smarter than I.